# Graphics drawing code generates blank images, only on iOS

Tags: ios, codenameone

My app displays some images that I created using Image.createImage(). In some cases, the images are completely blank, but only on iOS. The images work fine on Android. Also, I create several images using Image.createImage() and most of them work fine. I don't see any difference between those and these.

To reproduce, run the enclosed app on both Android and iOS. The app shows two images. The second one is taken from the bottom half of the first one. On Android, the images show up fine. On iOS, the images show up for a few seconds, then vanish. It turns out that they only show up while iOS is displaying the startup screen. Once it switches to the actual app, the images are blank, although they take up the same space. Further tests reveal that the images are the correct size but are filled with transparent pixels.

I should say that, in my actual application, the images scale with the size of the screen, and are colored according to a user preference, so I can't just load them from a resource.

(BTW Notice the change I made to the stop method. This is unrelated but worth mentioning.)

Here's the test case:

```
import com.codename1.ui.Component;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class HalfImageBug {

  private Form current;
  private Resources theme;

  public void init(Object context) {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

    // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

  }

  public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
      current.show();
      return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", new BorderLayout());
    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, makeComponent());
    hi.show();
  }

  public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();

    // This was originally if, but it should be while, in case there are multiple layers of dialogs.
    while (current instanceof Dialog) {
      ((Dialog) current).dispose();
      current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
    }
  }

  public void destroy() {
  }

  private Component makeComponent() {
    final Container container = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    container.setScrollableY(true);
    container.add(new Label("Full Image:"));
    Image fullIcon = createFullImage(0x44ff00, 40, 30);
    Label fullImage = new Label(fullIcon);
    container.add(fullImage);

    container.add(new Label("---"));
    container.add(new Label("Half Image:"));
    Image halfIcon = createHalfSizeImage(fullIcon);
    Label halfImage = new Label(halfIcon);
    container.add(halfImage);

    return container;
  }

  private Image createFullImage(int color, int verticalDiameter, int horizontalRadius) {

    // Make sure it's an even number. Otherwise the half image will have its right and left halves reversed!
    int diameter = (verticalDiameter / 2) * 2;
    final int iconWidth = 2 * horizontalRadius;
    int imageWidth = iconWidth + 2;
    int imageHt = diameter + 2;
    Image fullImage = Image.createImage(imageWidth, imageHt);
    Graphics g = fullImage.getGraphics();
    g.setAntiAliased(true);
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHt);
    g.setColor(darken(color, 25));
    g.fillArc(1, 1, iconWidth, diameter, 180, 360);
    g.setColor(0xbfbfbf);
    final int smallerHt = (9 * diameter) / 10;
    g.fillArc(0, 0, iconWidth, smallerHt, 180, 360);


    Image maskImage = Image.createImage(imageWidth, imageHt);
    g = maskImage.getGraphics();
    g.setAntiAliased(true);
    g.setColor(0);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHt);
    g.setColor(0xFF);
    g.fillArc(1, 1, iconWidth, diameter, 180, 360);
    fullImage = fullImage.applyMask(maskImage.createMask());

    return fullImage;
  }

  private Image createHalfSizeImage(Image fullImage) {
    int imageWidth = fullImage.getWidth();
    int imageHt = fullImage.getHeight();
    int[] rgbValues = fullImage.getRGB();
    // yeah, I've since discovered a much more sensible way to do this, but it doesn't fix the bug.
    int[] bottomHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(rgbValues, rgbValues.length / 2, rgbValues.length);
    //noinspection StringConcatenation
    Log.p("Cutting side image from " + imageWidth + " x " + imageHt + " to " + imageWidth + " x " + (imageHt / 2));
    return Image.createImage(bottomHalf, imageWidth, imageHt / 2);
  }

  private static int darken(int color, int percent) {
    if ((percent > 100) || (percent < 0)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Percent out of range: " + percent);
    }
    int percentRemaining = 100 - percent;
    return (darkenPrimary((color & 0xFF0000) >> 16, percentRemaining) << 16)
        | (darkenPrimary((color & 0xFF00) >> 8, percentRemaining) << 8)
        | (darkenPrimary(color & 0xFF, percentRemaining));
  }

  private static int darkenPrimary(int primaryValue, int percentRemaining) {
    if ((primaryValue < 0) || (primaryValue > 255)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Primary value out of range (0-255): " + primaryValue);
    }

    return (primaryValue * percentRemaining) / 100;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround. This works, but doesn't anti-alias very well. It will do until the iOS code gets fixed.

The problem is as described elsewhere. The Graphics.fillArc() and drawArc() methods work fine on Android, but often fail on iOS. Here's the behavior:

- if `width == height`, they correctly draw a circle.
- if `width < height`, they should draw an ellipse, but they draws a circle, centered over the intended ellipse, with a diameter equal to `width`.
- if `width > height`, they draw nothing.

The workaround draws a circle against a transparent background, then draws that circle, squeezed in one direction to an ellipse, into the proper place. It doesn't do a very good job of anti-aliasing, so this is not a good substitute for working code, but it will do until the bug gets fixed. (This workaround handles fillArc, but it shouldn't be hard to modify it for drawArc()

```
/**
 * Workaround for fillArc bug. Graphics.fillArc() works fine on android, but usually fails on iOS. There are three 
 * cases for its behavior.
 * 
 * If width < height, it draws a circle with a diameter equal to width, and concentric with the intended ellipse.<br>
 * If width > height, it draws nothing.<br>
 * If width == height, it works correctly.
 *
 * To work around this we create a separate image, draw a circle, re-proportion it to the proper ellipse, then draw 
 * it to the Graphics object. It doesn't anti-alias very well.
 */
public static void fillArcWorkaround(Graphics masterG, int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle) {
    if (width == height) {
        masterG.fillArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, arcAngle);
    } else {
        int max = Math.max(width, height);
        Image tempCircle = Image.createImage(max, max);
        Graphics tempG = tempCircle.getGraphics();
        tempG.setColor(masterG.getColor());
        tempG.fillRect(0, 0, max, max);

        // At this point tempCircle is just a colored rectangle. It becomes a circle when we apply the circle mask. The
        // region outside the circle becomes transparent that way.

        Image mask = Image.createImage(max, max);
        tempG = mask.getGraphics();
        tempG.setAntiAliased(masterG.isAntiAliased());
        tempG.setColor(0);
        tempG.fillRect(0, 0, max, max);
        tempG.setColor(0xFF); // blue
        tempG.fillArc(0, 0, max, max, startAngle, arcAngle);
        tempCircle = tempCircle.applyMask(mask.createMask());

        // Now tempCircle is a filled circle of the correct color. We now draw it in its intended proportions.

        masterG.setAntiAliased(true);
        masterG.drawImage(tempCircle, x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is marked as fixed, so we shouldn't be seeing this as soon as the new code gets released. For now, this workaround is an adequate solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1878).

Generally the images initially appear because of the screenshot process that shows them so they never really show up on iOS natively.

A common cause for these issues is creating images off of the EDT which doesn't seem to be the issue in this specific code.

It's hard to see what is going on so I guess we'll need to evaluate the issue.

Comment: I will be updating the test case shortly to present two similar images, one of which works and one which doesn't. That may be more helpful.

Comment: The Git-Hub issue posted here has been updated with a better test case. The new test case has three similar images. One doesn't work, one partly works, and one works completely.

Comment: I just posted my final test case. This time I posted it to the comments section of the Git-Hub issue. This new test case narrows down the problem to a single parameter. It turns out that, when drawing an arc, there are two possible outcomes. It either draws a perfect circle, even if it's not supposed to, or it draws nothing. If width <= height, it draws a circle. If width > height, it draws nothing. So it only draws correctly when width == height. See the code in the Git-hub issue for the test case, along with a useful illustration.

Comment: A better title for this issue would be this: Graphics.drawArc fails to draw correctly, only on iOS.